# Using Thymeleaf in Netbeans 7.1.2

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, thymeleaf

I've been using JSP/JSTL for a long time with Netbeans and Tomcat, but now I'm tired of the silly template engine, so I decided to try [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org). It works just fine so far, but whenever I save a Thymeleaf template, I need to redeploy my application for the template to update.

How do I make Netbeans automatically update the deployed template file when I save it?

(I couldn't add the "thymeleaf" tag because I have too few points.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to help when I disable caching of the template resolver.

Add this property to the template resolver bean:

```
<property name="cacheable" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Thymeleaf template resolvers cache parsed templates by default, in order to improve performance. Note this parsing only applies to templates themselves and not the data used for processing them.

As you say, you need to turn the `cacheable` property in the template resolver ([TemplateResolver.java](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.4/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/TemplateResolver.html#isCacheable%28%29)) to `false` if you want Thymeleaf to re-read your template every time it is processed:

```xml
<property name="cacheable" value="false" />
```